# "bus error" and "Segmentation fault" with a minimal code containing a struct in C

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, scanf, bus-error

I wrote a minimal C code as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct Books {
   char  title[50];
   char  author[50];
   char  subject[100];
   int   book_id;
};

int main() {
   struct Books Book1;

   char *tmp;
   int counter=0;

   scanf("%s", tmp);
   return 0;
}
```

When I compile and run the above code, after providing an input, I get the following error:

```
❯ gcc main.c
❯ ./a.out
e
[1]    86266 bus error  ./a.out
❯ vim main.c
$
```

I get a "Segmentation fault" when I put the above code in a function.

I have no idea what's wrong with this code. It works fine when I comment out first line main (the struct's instatioation). Any explanation would be appriciated.

Comment: Change `char *tmp` to something like `char tmp[1000]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tmp` is a pointer that isn't pointing anywhere.  It is *uninitialized*, meaning its value is *indeterminate*.  So when you pass this pointer to `scanf`, it attempt to dereference this invalid pointer.  This invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) which in your case causes the program to crash.

Change `tmp` into an array big enough to hold the value you want, and be sure to specify a maximum field size in your `scanf` format:

```
char tmp[50];
scanf("%49s", tmp);
```

Comment: But scanf suppose to work with char * as well, right? Why the code works when I comment out struct definition then?

Comment: @linker That's one of the ways undefined behavior can manifest itself.  A seemingly unrelated change can make your code crash (or not crash).

Comment: @linker: scanf expects the pointer to point to valid allocated memory. Either by allocating an array as shown, or you could allocate on the heap: `char *tmp = malloc(50);`.